# how to get changeLIst between two dates in perforce P4java API?

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec, p4java

I am trying to deal with perforce using P4JAVA API but I am not able to find the changelist between 2 different dates

if have to do this in command prompt I am using

```
p4 changes //depot/prod/...@2016/08/16,@2016/08/29
```

But in P4JAVA API I am not able to find the function.

Comment: I believe the function you want to call is GetChangelists() method on IOptionsServer.

Comment: These might help, but I'm not sure so I'm not posting them as answer(s):  

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/option/server/ChangelistOptions.html
https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/option/server/GetChangelistsOptions.html
https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/option/server/GetChangelistDiffsOptions.html

Comment: @BryanPendleton  it only return the changelist ID's

Comment: @BryanPendleton thanks . If you want to get the different then get the change list function and then use filediff() from the .util library with will help you out to get difference it just you have to get the actual revision for the file u want to diff